# In Minitest, switching to a JS driver makes assertions fail

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I am just not getting anywhere with Minitest when it comes to testing Javascript. Hopefully I am not bothering anyone by emitting so many questions.

So, now I managed to get Capybara working, and also was able to replace (some of) my existing tests with the new syntax (as the normal Minitest assertions won't work with Capybara).

```
test "study page & question screen" do

    assert_title "Study | Word Up"
    assert page.has_selector?('h3', text: "STUDY"), "Panel title missing or wrong"
    assert page.has_selector?("div.progress-bar"), "Progress bar missing or with wrong class"
end
```

Tests are green, all good.

```
16:24:23 - INFO - Running: test/integration/study/study_test.rb
Started

StudyTest
test_answer_screen                                              PASS (0.98s)
test_study_page_&_question_screen                               PASS (0.27s)

Finished in 1.26314s
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Now comes the Javascript part. I want to test for the presence of a `span` Element that I load with on-page Javascript. Therefor I switch drivers to use one that is capable of JS.

```
test "study page & question screen" do

    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    assert_title "Study | Word Up"
    assert page.has_selector?('h3', text: "STUDY"), "Panel title missing or wrong"
    assert page.has_selector?("div.progress-bar"), "Progress bar missing or with wrong class"
end
```

And suddenly the test is red as the first expectation is mysteriously not met.(Without even trying to test for JS content)

```
16:28:21 - INFO - Running: test/integration/study/study_test.rb
Started

StudyTest
test_answer_screen                                              PASS (1.12s)
test_study_page_&_question_screen                              ERROR (5.11s)
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:         Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected "" to include "Study | Word Up"
```

But, as If this wasn't weird enough, when taking out all the non-JS-tests and only test for an element I insert via on-page JS:

```
test "study page & question screen" do

    Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
    Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
    #assert_title "Study | Word Up"
    #assert page.has_selector?('h3', text: "STUDY"), "Panel title missing or wrong"
    #assert page.has_selector?("div.progress-bar"), "Progress bar missing or with wrong class"
    assert page.has_selector?('span'), "Frontside missing or wrong" 
end
```

I get a failing test:

```
16:49:06 - INFO - Running: test/integration/study/study_test.rb
Started

StudyTest
test_answer_screen                                              PASS (0.99s)
test_study_page_&_question_screen                               FAIL (4.19s)
Minitest::Assertion:         Frontside missing or wrong
```

Right now, I feel like I am randomly trying combinations of methods and drivers, and I don't know where to go from now. Is it just me or is the documentation of minitest and of the mentioned Gems a bit too compact. I hope I don't offend anyone by saying so, or asking that. Probably it is just because I don't have a lot of experience in using gems and combining them.